# How to work with initialize.php?

Tags: php

I want to learn and work with **initialize.php** so I try to build simple php file like **index.php** and just to see if it call to **hello.php** I got some truble on my local host using windows xp.

the details are:

**http://127.0.0.1/www/oop/shape2/index.php**
the file **index.php**

```
<?php
    defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', '/');
    defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :defined('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

    echo (LIB_PATH.DS.'hello.php');
    require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'hello.php');
?>
```

**the output is:**

```
SITE_ROOT/includes/hello.php
```

**http://127.0.0.1/www/oop/shape2/includes/hello.php**
the file **hello.php**

```
<?php
 echo ('hi');
 ?>
```

if i run it I got `hi`

here is my local folder on windows:
**C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\www\oop\shape2**

what shell I do slove the problem.
Thx

Comment: What is a "initialize.php"???

Comment: note that "echo hi;" is wrong, and will issue a warning (that "hi" means you are using a constant). If you want to print out "hi", you need to use: echo "hi"; (with either double - " - or single -' - quotes around hi).

Comment: It's possible to upload all the files that are in a directory or multiple directories by location relative to reading file

Comment: You are probably not aware of the `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` constants. http://php.net/language.constants.predefined.

Comment: Don't abuse ternary operations like that. If it *must* be one line, use `OR`. Example: `defined('FOO') OR define('FOO', 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second line, you should change

`defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :defined('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

to

`defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :define('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

You were calling the `defined` function rather than the `define` function, meaning you never actually created the SITE_ROOT constant.

Comment: is that correct `<?php
 defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', '/');
 defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :define('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
 defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');

 echo (LIB_PATH.DS.'hello.php');
 require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'hello.php');
?>` the out put are:C:/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/includes/hello.php

Comment: That code is completely unreadable in that state... But I guess that looks good. Did you also actually try it out?

Comment: yes, the out put are: C:/Program Files/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/includes/hello.php

Comment: So does that mean the problem was solved? Are you now able to include your file?